# I'm stuck with my SELECT sql query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having a problem with my SELECT sql statement and I haven't figured it out yet. When I print out the results using `mysql_fetch_assoc()` function, I get repetitive rows/records. A record is repeated 13 times. I don't know why and I have done it right as far as my knowledge tells me.

The following is my sql query:

```
SELECT 
    members.member_id, 
    members.firstname, 
    members.lastname, 
    billing_details.Street_Address, 
    billing_details.Mobile_No, 
    orders_details.*, 
    food_details.*, 
    categories.*, 
    cart_details.*, 
    quantities.* 
FROM 
    members, billing_details, orders_details, categories, 
    quantities, food_details, cart_details 
WHERE 
    members.member_id=orders_details.member_id AND 
    billing_details.billing_id=orders_details.billing_id AND 
    orders_details.cart_id=cart_details.cart_id AND 
    cart_details.food_id=food_details.food_id AND 
    cart_details.quantity_id=quantities.quantity_id
```

Comment: Add your tables one by one in the query - then you'll find at which stage there is an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't have "categories" in your WHERE clause.  I am guessing you have 13 categories?  If you need a better explanation, let me know.

Comment: @marlaw21 to avoid such errors, either use joins or sort the where part so that you have them in the same order like the tables in the `FROM` part

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT`.

**Please Note**

Using the `mysql_*` libraries is bad practise. They are **Deprecated** and should be replaced by either the `mysqli_*` libraries or a `PDO` object.

Comment: It's a competition? Okay. MINE TALKS ABOUT GOOD PRACTICE SO THERE!!

Comment: Badges and "reputation"? Yeah, it is.

Comment: Shrug. Reputation is a reflection of how you answer. It's a competition if you want it to be. I think the badges and rep are just there to give a numerical rating at how much of an asset to the site you are.

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you make left Joins like below

```
SELECT members.member_id, members.firstname, members.lastname, billing_details.Street_Address, billing_details.Mobile_No, orders_details.*, food_details.*, categories.*, cart_details.*, quantities.* FROM members as m

Left join billing_details as b ON b.billing_id=m.?
LEFT JOIN orders_details as o ON o.cart_id=m.?
LEFT JOIN food_details as f ON f.f_id =m.? 
LEFT JOIN cart_details as c ON c.?=?
LEFT JOIN quantitiesas q  ON q.?=?
LEFT JOIN categories as cat ON cat.?=?
```

Comment: Where is the question mark before the equals sign documented?

Comment: @JanusTroelsen Column name has to be added by the user himself as I dont know what column structure he has in his tables :)

Answer (score 0):

If you only want each member_id to appear once, you can use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT members.member_id, ...
```

You can also use `JOIN USING` to avoid repetition (DRY):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html (search for `USING(column_list)`)

That way, you'd also have noticed the msising predicate, since it would be right next to the joined table name.